# pandas DataFrame: пересчет колонки, применяя условия

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'v': [0, 0, 0], 'a': [95.71, 6.61, 80], 'p': [88.57, 4.55, 60]})
c = float(1 + ((p + 6.9) + ((p + 6.9)/100 * 4.5)))

res = float()

def func():
    d = a - c
    if d > 1:
        if d / 100 * 20 >= 1:
            res = float(a - (d / 100 * 20))
        else:
            res = float(a - 1)
    else:
        res = float(c)
    return res


if c >= 75 and c >= a:
    res = float(c)
elif c >= 75 and c < a:
    res = float(func())
elif c < 75:
    c = float(1 + (p + (p / 100 * 4.5)))
    if c > a:
        res = float(c)
    elif c < a:
        res = float(func())

df['a'] = res
```

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как пересчитать колонку "p" с помощью формулы? Результат должен попасть в колонку "v"

Есть рабочий код но без участия DataFrame

```
a = (80)
b = (60)
c = float(1 + ((b + 6.9) + ((b + 6.9)/100 * 4.5)))
res = float()
def func():
    d = a - c
    if d > 1:
        if d / 100 * 20 >= 1:
            res = float(a - (d / 100 * 20))
        else:
            res = float(a - 1)
    else:
        res = float(c)
    return res


if c >= 75 and c >= a:
    res = float(c)
elif c >= 75 and c < a:
    res = float(func())
elif c < 75:
    c = float(1 + (b + (b / 100 * 4.5)))
    if c > a:
        res = float(c)
    elif c < a:
        res = float(func())

print(res)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: я извеняюсь, за неполное описание вопроса. Голова кипить.

Comment: Спасибо розобрался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Несколько раз перечитал ваш вопрос - то так и не понял. Естественно, первый код не рабочий, а второй непонятно что делает.

Поэтому даю ответ на ту часть вашего вопроса, которую понять удалось, а именно "как пересчитать колонку "p" с помощью формулы? Результат должен попасть в колонку "v"

Вот ваш исходный датафрейм

```
   v      a      p
0  0  95.71  88.57
1  0   6.61   4.55
2  0  80.00  60.00
```

Вот код

```
df.v=1 + ((df.p + 6.9) + ((df.p + 6.9)/100 * 4.5))
```

Вот полученный результат:

```
         v      a      p
0  100.76615  95.71  88.57
1   12.96525   6.61   4.55
2   70.91050  80.00  60.00
```

Если надо передать несколько параметров в функцию apply, делается это примерно так:

```
def rule(x, y):
    if ......:
         return 1
    else:
         return 0
df.v = incidence.apply(lambda x: rule(x.a, x.b), axis =  1)
```

Comment: Спасибо, что помагеете. попробую разеснить. Как видете колонка "v" в вашем ответе и в моей таблице отличаются, вот тот дополнительный код и сравнивет сначала если результат переменой "с" больше 75 и больше чем значение в колонке "а", то результат "с" копруем в колонку  "v" если нет проганям по остальным условиям. Это формула расчета цена между поставщиками и другими магазинами для своего магазаина. другими словами цена ддолжна быть меньше чем удругих. в формуле заложены до 75$ только платежная система 4,5% +1$, все что больше 75 закладывается еще и доставка

Comment: Естественно если зазор большой то цену мы делаем чуть  ниже чем удругих, а потом делаем акции и скидки на данный товар

Comment: В Pandas есть метод apply, которые как раз и позволяет пройтись по строчкам и для каждой строки выполнить тербуемое действие, в том числе с проверкой условия, а результат записать в другой столбец этой же строки. В качестве параметра указанного метода можна даже использовать некоторую отдельно написанную функцию, возвращающую требуемое расчетное значение. Пользуйтесь.

Comment: Да Вы правы, но apply(lambda x: x >75) принимает лиш одно условие. А если, apply(func) то проблема с передачей двух аргументов

Comment: Как?? Принимает столько, сколько надо без проблем. Вот возвращать по логике должно только одно, то которое надо записать в качестве нового значения. Пример добавил в конец ответа.

Comment: А что это за - incidence. Если не тяжело, розяснить или сылку на мануал. Спасибо

Comment: Исправил. Больше нет incidence. :-) (Это было название датафрейма)